# How to transform a List[Map[String, String]] in Scala

Tags: scala, transform

I have a Scala `List` of `Map[String, String]` like this:

```
val data: List[Map[String, String]] = List(Map("key" -> "123", "fname" -> "Alice", "lname" -> "Baker"), Map("key" -> "456", "fname" -> "Bob", "lname" -> "Lotts"))
```

I want to transform this to a `List` like this: `List(Map(id -> 123, name -> Alice Baker), Map(id -> 456, name -> Bob Lotts))`. Basically, I need to change the `key` to `id` and concatenate the `fname` and `lname` to `name`.

I tried the below code. It works, but I am sure there should be a better way of doing this. Can anyone please suggest?

```
val modData: List[Map[String, String]] = data.map(d => Map("id" -> d.getOrElse("key", ""), "name" -> s"${d.getOrElse("fname", "")} ${d.getOrElse("lname", "")}"))
```

Comment: That is the right way of doing it, maybe the only advice would be to use a `case class` instead of `Map[String, String]` and maybe using `Either` to collect errors instead of defaulting to an empty string.

Comment: Is pretty simple: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/TBhu0T9uTwmQLiZSS1MWsA/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in steps, and use default for the map to make it more readable:

```
    val keys = Seq("key", "fname", "lname")
    list.iterator
      .map(_.withDefault(_ => ""))
      .map(keys.map)
      .collect { case Seq(id, fname, lname) => Map("id" -> id, "name" -> s"$fname $lname") }
      .toList
```